# How to create a spaceship and force field transition effect

Tags: shaders, collision, dynamic-paint

I have put together a scene in which a space fighter exits a force field from a carrier. I would like to create an effect that when the fighter flies through the force field, the field glows darker as the ship transitions through it, then the field returns to it's original status once the ship passed through. The force field was created with a mesh and some shading. I then added a dynamic paint canvass to the field, and a dynamic paint brush to the ship but that isn't working. I am including an image of my setup. Am unsure at this point what to do. Maybe add a collision object? Can someone please assist me with setting this up? Am using Blender 2.91. With thanks

The effect I am looking for wouold be similar to this video on Youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6IW4Y9i-vE

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a reference image of what you expect to get.

Comment: Thanks mate. I found a very short video of the effect I would be looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sci-fi energy shield (force shield, force barrier VFX) is fairly easy to create with *Dynamic Paint*.

[image: animated energy shield]

You just need ...

- a subdivided plane that is the *Canvas* for the *Dynamic Paint* physics. Set *Surface Type* to `Waves` and tick the `Open Borders` checkbox. Add a *Solidify* modifier if you want to look at the shield from both sides.
- an object (a spaceship or Suzanne) that is the *Brush*. Increase *Waves > Factor* to `2` to enhance the effect
- create a shader that uses the y coordinate of the wave deformation to colorize the shield. In the material settings set *Blend Mode* to `Alpha Blend` and enable *Bloom* in Eevee render settings. [image: transparent emission shader]

In Blender 2.92+ you can use a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier and *Geometry Nodes* to add some sparkle. Just create a vertex group ("proxy"), assign all mesh vertices to it, and use it in the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier and for the *Density Attribute* of the *Point Distribute* node in the *Geometry* node setup. [image: screenshot of the modifiers]

[image: geometry nodes for sparkle]

In the example, both objects (the plane and Suzanne) have each a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier and a set of *Geometry* nodes to have the little spheres on both objects when they are close together.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works very well, although when I up the Density Max to 256, my laptop comes to a crawl so I have adjusted that Max Density to compensate. Thanks again, I really appreciate the time you took to show me. Cheers!!

Comment: A really nice combination for this effect. I love the way it grabs bits from all over Blender.