# How to convert a wet or paint map to a weight map

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights, dynamic-paint

Using dynamic paint in Blender 2.93.4, a wet map and a paint map can be created for vertex colors. The 'Tissue' add-on include a command to convert to weight in vertex paint mode.
[image]

However, when this command is used, the resulting weight map is empty and the paint or wet information is lost.

1. Is there a way to make this command work and get a weight map from the dynamic paint map?
2. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Seems not to work this way. Looks like you can manually paint the vertex colors. But when Dynamic Paint is enabled it overwrites it. The Tissue command on the other hand seems always to use your manually painted data.

Comment: 2. bake the Dynamic Paint to an image sequence or use the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier?

Comment: @Blunder Can you point to an example of using the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier?

Comment: It depends on what you have in mind. Here is an example that uses VWP and DP: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209336/how-to-create-a-spaceship-and-force-field-transition-effect/218230#218230 - If you want to control particles with it then it's better to bake the Dynamic Paint and use the created image sequence because the weight painting by the modifiers doesn't work properly for particles. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12278/107598 for details.